# ACF Flexible content - basic text field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

i'm working on acf custom fields with flexible content with wordpress. I'd like to make some flexible content appear, so I use the code I found on acf website.
Then I create the fields on acf, but nothing appear.

[• Here is what I made on acf : the name of the fexible content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJn2D.png)
[• and here are the sub fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQyCv.png)

> This is just text area and normal texte title

• here is my code

```
<?php /* Template Name: ateliers */ ?>


<?php get_header(); ?>






<?php if(have_posts()) : ?><?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('ateliers') ):

     // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('atelieratelier') ) : the_row();

        if( get_row_layout() == 'content' ):

            the_sub_field('atelier_01');


        elseif( get_row_layout() == 'content' ): 

            the_sub_field('texte_atelier');

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no layouts found

endif;

?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `if( get_row_layout() == 'content' ):` doesn't exist. That should equal the name you're pulling for the flexible content type. `atelieratelier` in your case. Looks like you only have one row layout type.

Comment: @Aibrean : thank you ! I search for hours, but it was as simple. It was tough to find this information : what is "row", what is "field", what is "layout". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go ahead and write a proper answer for this one...

Row: `ateliers`

Field: `atelier_01` and `texte_atelier`

Layout: `atelieratelier`

Your if/while should both be the row.

```
 <?php if (have_rows('ateliers')){ ?>
     <?php while (have_rows('ateliers')) { the_row(); ?>
     <!--start the row layout-->
       <?php if (get_row_layout() == 'atelieratelier') { ?>
         <?php the_sub_field('atelier_01')?>
         <?php the_sub_field('texte_atelier')?>
       <?php }?> <!--if you had more layouts you would do an elseif or migrate to a switch statement-->
      <!--end the row layout-->
     <?php } // while   ?>
    <?php } ?>
```